# C# telerik Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I'm new in C# I have a question. 
I'm using telerik and I get an error using an object initialized in the Load_page method.

This is my code:

```
public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page {
private Customer customer;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack){
        customer = new Customer();
        customer.Name = "John";
   }
}

protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MessageBox.Show(customer.Name); //error customer is null
}
```

}

Why customer is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because HTTP is stateless protocol. On button click, page will load again and it forget all about `customer` you intialized previously. You either need to maintain `session` or put it in page load outside `!Page.IsPostBack` block

Answer (score 3):

Customer is null, because when the page posts back the `Test` page instance has to be constructed again, at this point it has no customer.

When `Page_Load` is called, you suppress creating a customer if it's a postback (that's what the button click does - posts back).

Therefore when you attempt to show the customer's name the customer is null. What you need to do is persist this customer somehow (either in a database, viewstate, transmit to the client and back again).

Also note that you shouldn't show a `MessageBox` in a web application!

Comment: Thank you, I will store it in session. It is actually the same solution I'd used with other languages.
Thank you.

p.s. Yes Messagebox was a wrong placeolder.